# Timer IllegalArgumentException with positive delay

Tags: android

I've come across a crash report in one of my apps that appears to be something that should never happen in my code...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:461)
at com.pilot51.voicenotify.Service.onAccessibilityEvent(Service.java:177)
at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IEventListenerWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:215)
at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:61)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the relevant code for that revision:

```
int delay = 0;
try {
    delay = Integer.parseInt(Common.prefs.getString("ttsDelay", null));
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

if (delay > 0) {
    final String msg = newMsg;
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() { // This is line 177
        public void run() {
            speak(msg, true);
        }
    }, delay * 1000);
}
```

Full source: https://github.com/pilot51/voicenotify/blob/v1.0.9.1/src/com/pilot51/voicenotify/Service.java

I checked the Timer source and verified that IAE should only happen if `delay < 0`, yet I have a check that `delay > 0`. On top of that, unless there's some poorly designed custom keyboard that ignores input type/digits (is that even possible?), the user can only enter numbers 0-9 in the text field, no negative sign or period or anything else.

Since I am unable to reproduce the crash or communicate with any users experiencing it, I am unable to debug it. The relative number of reports is high enough to have me a little concerned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer probably overflew. For example value  3000000 multiplied by 1000 cannot be expressed in 32 bit integer. The result would be negative.

Comment: Thanks! Before posting, I tried setting it to a ridiculously large number even beyond the range of long and it didn't crash (left at 0 when NFE caught). I didn't think about testing large numbers within range since I wasn't aware they become negative when calculated out of range and, well, wasn't thinking. Now I understand. Quick fix was to change `1000` to `1000L` so it passes as a long. One mystery remains: Why would anyone set a delay between 2147484 and 2147483647 seconds?